# SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such device

Tags: debian, kernel, drivers, network-interface, ethernet

I am having issues while trying to enable `eth0` interface on my Pine64 SBC.

I am running the following Armbian version:

```
Title:          Armbian 5.38.180128 Pine64 Debian stretch next
Kernel:         Linux 4.14.15
Build date:     28.01.2018
```

I am able to connect a USB 2.0 to Ethernet adapter without any issues. The problem arises when I try to enable `eth0` which is the Native Ethernet port.

```
pine64:/# ifconfig eth0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such device

pine64:/# dmesg | grep eth0
xxxxxx.ethernet eth0: Could not attach to PHY
```

The file `var/log/messages` shows the following:

```
device (eth0): driver '(null)' does not support carrier detection
device (eth0): driver 'unknown' does not support carrier detection
```

It definitely looks like a driver issue but reinstalling the following did not help:

```
firmware-linux-nonfree
firmware-linux
```

Setting network manager to ignore the carrier and restarting network services yielded no results:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
ignore_carrier=eth0
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your network interface has the name `eth0`? Debian has moved to "predictable network interface names", and away from names like `eth0`. Try running the command `ip link` to see a listing of the interfaces.